# Nested Collection with KnockoutJs and Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have this .net class below

```
public class JobDetailsDTO
{
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public String[] IndustryName;
}
```

**i am trying to map this to a Knockout JS model, my nested collection is not working looks like, what am i doing wrong in the JS model?**

```
var jobViewModel = {
    jobDetailsDTO: ko.observableArray(),
    currentPage: ko.observable(-1),
    industries: ko.observableArray(industries),
    contentLoadTriggered: false
};
```

Here is my  data bind

```
<div id="jobcontent-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: jobDetailsDTO">
    <label data-bind="text: JobName"></label>
    <span class="jobsize" data-bind="text: CompanyName"> </span>
    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: industries">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
        Industry
        <span class="jobsize" data-bind="text: IndustryName"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="jobcontent-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: jobDetailsDTO">
    <label data-bind="text: JobName"></label>
    <span class="jobsize" data-bind="text: CompanyName"> </span>
    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: industries">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
        Industry
        <span class="jobsize" data-bind="text: IndustryName"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my ajax to get data

```
function getData(pageNumber) {
    if (jobViewModel.currentPage() != pageNumber) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "/api/jobservice/getjob",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { id: pageNumber }
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    jobViewModel.jobDetailsDTO.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the JSOn that i get from my controller

> [{"IndustryName":["RIE","XSL","FWTI","QPCAP","PPGPUU"],"JobName":"KLLFBN","CompanyName":"CKI"},{"IndustryName":["SAF","JIF","MVFG","RPAIP","ALAUKM"],"JobName":"ROULJS","CompanyName":"LXN"},{"IndustryName":["IIH","PEM","TINE","EOAXF","ZYJHKK"],"JobName":"ISUYFV","CompanyName":"VZR"}]

**When i disable this line in my view model it works to pull the data, but when i enable this line it  does not execute any JS after that point. my assumption is there is something wrong with how i have defined the child collection. i do not see any err msg on console on Firefox firebug**

```
var jobViewModel = {
    jobDetailsDTO: ko.observableArray(),
    currentPage: ko.observable(-1),
    industries: ko.observableArray(industries), ///this line
    contentLoadTriggered: false
};
```

Comment: Can you add the Controller Code?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?
Does `jobDetailsDTO` in `jobViewModel` has a list of `industries`,
Make sure the `jobDetailsDTO` in viewmodel `jobViewModel`  has `JobName`, `CompanyName`, and a list of `industries`

Comment: You need to be more specific, "xyz is not working it looks like" is a bit too vague. Help us repro this issue (with only the *relevant* code), tell us what specific error you get and where, etc.

Comment: @Jeroen have updated some details, my guess is that the child collection being defined is failing in KO js library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any mention of the `industries` variable in your code, before the initialization of the `jobViewModel` object. Could the problem be that you don't have any object set to the `industries` variable?

I think what you should do is that you should remove the line in the `jobViewModel` initialization which you are referring to. Then, since your returned JSON has a property called `IndustryName` which is an array of string (and no property called `industries`), I think you should also rewrite your html binding to something similar to the following (the changes from your original binding is on lines 4 and 7):

```
1. <div id="jobcontent-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: jobDetailsDTO">
2.     <label data-bind="text: JobName"></label>
3.     <span class="jobsize" data-bind="text: CompanyName"> </span>
4.     <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: IndustryName">
5.         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
6.         Industry
7.         <span class="jobsize" data-bind="text: $data"></span>
8.     </div>
9. </div>
```